# return same html page when requesting

Tags: python, python-requests

I get the same html pages when trying with different urls in the same webpage
I have tried many times but i didn't get the expected result

```
import requests
req=requests.get('https://cricbuzz.com')
reqq=requests.get('https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match-highlights/22487/kxip-vs-kkr-52nd-match-indian-premier-league-2019')
print(req.text)
print(reqq.text)
```

both print statements returns the same html page,but actually tthis is not the expected result

Comment: Are you sure that the page doesn’t have JavaScript that creates the page you are expecting?

Comment: Do those pages have different content when accessed in a browser?

Comment: Some sites wild redirect to the start page if you send an invalid request.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the same page (or at least I am not with your examples)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup1 = bs(requests.get('https://cricbuzz.com').content, 'lxml')
soup2 = bs(requests.get('https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match-highlights/22487/kxip-vs-kkr-52nd-match-indian-premier-league-2019').content, 'lxml')

print(soup1.select_one('[rel=canonical]')['href'])
print(soup2.select_one('[rel=canonical]')['href'])
```

[image]

You could also have done

```
print(req.text == reqq.text)
```